# Getting segmentation fault when freeing binary tree recursively

Tags: c

I am working with binary trees in C (Linux Debian, gcc version 4.9.2) and I am having some troubles when freeing memory allocated by malloc. The first deltree() works fine but the second deltree() gives me a segmentation fault. What could be the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
  compiling with flags -ansi -Wstrict-prototypes
*/

struct treenode{
  struct treenode *left;
  struct treenode *right;
  int data;
};

typedef struct treenode node;

void deltree(node *tree);

int main(void){
  node *root;

  printf("First tree\n");
  printf("===================\n");

  root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->data=5;

  root->left=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->left->data=4;

  root->right=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->right->data=6;

  printf("Root node has data %d\n",root->data);
  printf("Left child has data %d\n",root->left->data);
  printf("Right child has data %d\n",root->right->data);

  deltree(root);  /* NO PROBLEM HERE */

  printf("Second tree\n");
  printf("===================\n");

  root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->data=-7;

  root->left=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->left->data=-5;

  root->right=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  root->right->data=-1;

  printf("Root node has data %d\n",root->data);
  printf("Left child has data %d\n",root->left->data);
  printf("Right child has data %d\n",root->right->data);

  deltree(root); /* SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE */

  printf("Finished\n");

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void deltree(node *tree){
  if(tree!=NULL){
    deltree(tree->left);
    deltree(tree->right);

    printf(".\n");

    free(tree);
  }
}
```

Comment: Aside: Rather than `root=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));`, suggest `root=malloc(sizeof *root);`  Easier to code/maintain and less likely to code wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize the `left` and `right` pointers after allocation so their value is undefined.

Either use `calloc` or set the pointers to `NULL` manually.

Comment: Thank you. Certainly, I forgot to set the leaf nodes to NULL.